# Javascript .call function returning extra 'undefined' value

Tags: javascript, call

In the following snippet:

```
function Product(name, price) {
  this.name = name;
  this.price = price;
  this.show = function() {
      console.log(this.name);
      console.log(this.price * 10);
      };
}

function Food(name, price) {
  Product.call(this, name, price);
  this.category = 'food';
}

function Toy(name, price) {
  Product.call(this, name, price);
  this.category = 'toy';
}

var cheese = new Food('feta', 5);
var fun = new Toy('robot', 40);

console.log(fun.show());
```

The console output I am getting is:

```
robot
400
undefined
```

Why is the third output coming as `undefined` and from where is it coming?

Comment: `show` doesnt return anything, but you are logging the return.

Comment: what would you expect it to return and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, JS functions return undefined.

Since your `show` function isn't explicitly returning anything, it returns undefined.

Comment: I would add that the OP probably wants to replace: `console.log(fun.show());` with: `fun.show();` since 1) `show()` is already calling `console.log` and 2) `show()` doesn't return anything (which means that it effectively returns `undefined` as you suggested)

Answer (score 1):

Use `return` instead of logging to the console multiple times.

```
function Product(name, price) {
  this.name = name;
  this.price = price;
  this.show = function() {
      return this.name + " " + String(this.price * 10)
  };
}

function Food(name, price) {
  Product.call(this, name, price);
  this.category = 'food';
}

function Toy(name, price) {
  Product.call(this, name, price);
  this.category = 'toy';
}

var cheese = new Food('feta', 5);
var fun = new Toy('robot', 40);

console.log(fun.show());
```

Produces: `robot 400` (toy name and price)